# Using R to filter conditions within conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a dataset that has 4 columns, home_team, away_team, home_score and away_score which contains scores for 18 teams.

I'm trying to return the 2 games played between 2 specific teams in one command. I can do this separately using the dplyr package:

```
game1 <- data %>%
        select(Home_team, Away_team, home_score, away_score) %>%
        filter(Home_team == "Team1", Away_team == "Team2")

game2 <- data %>%
        select(Home_team, Away_team, home_score, away_score) %>%
        filter(Home_team == "Team2", Away_team == "Team")
```

I can't seem to find a way to return the results of the 2 games in one go, as Home_team and Away_team are 2 specific conditions. I need (Home_team=Team1 AND Away_team=Team2) to be one condition AND (Away_team=Team1 AND HOME_team=Team2) to be another condition.

Is there any way to get this output? I've tried to do it within the filter function in dplyr using AND and OR (|) with no success but perhaps there is another package/function that can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried something like `Home_team == c("Team1", "Team2"), Away_team == c("Team1", "Team2")`?

Comment: You can use ‘&’ operator as AND and ‘|’ operator as OR to connect multiple filter conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dr. Flow says ... this should do what you want

```
games <- data %>%
        select(Home_team, Away_team, home_score, away_score) %>%
        filter((Home_team == "Team1" & Away_team == "Team2") |
               (Home_team == "Team2" & Away_team == "Team1"))
```

Does it work?

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
N = 50

data = data.frame(Home_team = sample(paste0("Team",1:3), N, replace = TRUE),
                  Away_team = sample(paste0("Team",1:3), N, replace = TRUE),
                  home_score = rbinom(N, 5, 0.2),
                  away_score = rbinom(N, 3, 0.2)) %>% 
        filter(Home_team != Away_team)

games <- data %>%
  select(Home_team, Away_team, home_score, away_score) %>%
  filter((Home_team == "Team1" & Away_team == "Team2") |
           (Home_team == "Team2" & Away_team == "Team1"))
```

```
> games
  Home_team Away_team home_score away_score
1     Team2     Team1          2          1
2     Team2     Team1          0          0
3     Team2     Team1          3          0
4     Team1     Team2          0          1
5     Team2     Team1          0          1
6     Team1     Team2          0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wouldn't have `home_team == away_team`, you can formulate it as

```
teams <- c("Team1", "Team2")
games <- data %>%
    select(Home_team, Away_team, home_score, away_score) %>%
    filter(Home_team %in% teams, Away_team %in% teams)
```